# Libgdx BodyEditorLoader android error

Tags: android, libgdx

i'm using libgdx 0.9.8. For creating box2d object i'm using the physics-body-editor-2.9.2(https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/downloads/list).
My problem is that whenever i load the json file created by the physics-body-editor, into the libgdx project, using the code:

```
BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("data/upspring-object.json"));
```

i get an error on the android device, saying "unfortunately the app stopped!".
But everything works fine when i launch the desktop version on the computer.
Please kindly suggest the solutions.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Have you managed to fix it?